# How to parse XML feed URL and store items in Firestore using cloud functions?

Tags: node.js, xml, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have been given an assignment to fetch a JSON API, and also parse an XML feed URL and store their responses inside separate Firestore collections. I am not really good at cloud functions, but after lots of research, I have written the cloud function code below for the JSON API and it works well.

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const axios = require("axios");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");


const api_token = "XXXXXXX";
const includes = "XXXXXX";
const url = "https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXX.com/?api_token=" + api_token + includes;

exports.allLeagues = functions.region('europe-west1').https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    try {
        let response = await axios.get(url);
        var data = response.data.data;
            
            for (let leagueData of data) {
                await admin.firestore().collection("leagues").doc(leagueData.id.toString()).collection("all_data").doc(leagueData.id.toString()).set({
                    id : leagueData.id,
                    name : leagueData.name,
                    logo_path : leagueData.logo_path,
                    is_cup : leagueData.is_cup
                });
            }
            console.log("Table complete...");

        console.log("successful");
        return res.status(200).json({ message: "successful" });
    } catch(error) {
        console.log("Error encountered: "+error);
        return res.status(500).json({ error });
    }
});
```

I am through with the JSON API. But for the XML feed, I don't know where to start. I have done lots of research to no avail. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49513229/how-parse-given-website-and-insert-data-into-firebase-using-firebase-functions) on Stackoverflow but it doesn't address my need. Assuming this is my feed: https://www.feedforall.com/sample.xml , please how do I parse it and save the items inside Firestore?
Kindly help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [rss-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rss-parser) that can be used to fetch data from RSS feeds or parse from XML strings as shown below:

```
// npm install rss-parser

const Parser = require("rss-parser");
const parser = new Parser();

exports.rssFeedParser = functions.https.onRequest(
  async (request, response) => {
    const rssUrl = "https://www.feedforall.com/sample.xml";
    const feed = await parser.parseURL(rssUrl);
    const { items } = feed;

    const batch = db.batch();

    items.forEach((item) => {
      const docRef = db.collection("rss").doc(); 
      // restructure item if needed
      batch.set(docRef, item);
    });

    await batch.commit();
    response.send("Done");
  }
);
```

Do note that you can add up to 500 documents only using [Batched Writes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes) as in the answer above. If your feed can return more than that, then you should create multiple batches of 500 or add them individually.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I will try it and come back to accept the answer.